# ASP.NET Core identity Server does not have access to host endpoint from itself

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

Currently we have a well working SPA on the internet with ASP.NET Core 7.0 and identity server for the backend.

But now we are selling it to another organization for their internal use on their Lan.

But they have some constraint on their network setup, such as reverse proxy and not allowing one machine to call itself.

You have access to all the endpoints everywhere in the network except the current machine

If you call `https://Company.com/.well-known/openid-configuration` from client you would get the result.

But if you call it from host machine, you would get nothing.

And that's the problem, since identity server use the same address for reading it's configuration.

A lot of log with this message:

> Unable to obtain configuration from URL

What I need is to force/config identityServer to call localhost instead of request URL.

And even by that I'm not sure if it's the right call, since it seems for security reasons, both server and client should use same address for validation (or something like this, please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Navigating your network constraints is tricky but possible. You could modify IdentityServer to use localhost for internal calls. Another option is editing the server's hosts file to reroute `Company.com` to `127.0.0.1`. If you control the LAN's DNS, set it to resolve `Company.com` to the local IP for server requests. You could also configure your reverse proxy to route such requests to localhost. Be cautious: altering URLs could pose security risks. Test thoroughly before deploying.

Comment: What happens if you set options.Audience = "https://Company.com/.well-known/openid-configuration";
options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
options.MetadataAddress = "http://1.2.3.4/.well-known/openid-configuration";    Where 1.2.3.4 is the local IP or internal name of the IdentityServer instace?

Comment: @ToreNestenius let me this test this and I will notify if it worked to change your comment to answer.

Comment: @ToreNestenius thanx alot, that's solved the issue (i was using AddIdentityServerAuthentication method, which is outdated and not supported by dev team any more, and this particular method does not have metadataAddress and i spend a lot of time figuring it out), if you like change your comment to answer so i could accept it

Comment: Oh, great! Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set:

```
options.Audience = "https://Company.com/.well-known/openid-configuration"; 
options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; 
options.MetadataAddress = "http://1.2.3.4/.well-known/openid-configuration";
```

Where 1.2.3.4 is the local IP or internal name of the IdentityServer instace?

In this way, you separate the what should be the address inside the tokens and from where the application gets its metadata.